# How to deal with large transient data in oracle function used in select statements?

Tags: oracle

Inserts are usually not allowed in select statements, and using collections can be problematic for larger data since they are kept in memory. Using pipelined functions would potentially perform the same query multiple times. Using stored procedures would mean performing the query piecewise and using even more transient data between the parts.
So how can such data be kept through the function life for repeated use?

Comment: What do you mean by "transient data"? When you open a cursor in Oracle then it will retrieve the data which is present at the moment when the cursor was opened. Data which changes while the cursor is processed (no matter if line by line or bulk processing) has no effect on the cursor data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit By transient data I meant data that is not persisted in the database beyond the life of the function, not inserted in any table. Not data that changes.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Like for example, if I open a cursor as you said, then I may have to keep its result through the function life cycle and perform various calculations with it, or checks etc.

Comment: Look into GTTs (global temporary tables).

Comment: @PaulW Thanks. Someone wrote a post suggesting GTT won't work https://copyprogramming.com/howto/ora-14551-cannot-perform-a-dml-operation-inside-a-query

Comment: The body of your question made no reference to this PL/SQL being called from a select statement; I see now that's suggested however by your title. That should be clearer. It's going to be hard to further advise without understanding what role this SQL-called function has. Is it producing rows like a table in the FROM clause or is it returning a scalar and called within either the SELECT or WHERE clause?

Comment: @PaulW It is returning a scalar. But both cases interest me. :)

Comment: If a scalar, you probably have an architectural problem - you shouldn't be doing that amount of work in a SQL-called function that returns a scalar. That stretches the intent of SQL functions. Rearchitect it so you gather the data you need in the SQL itself, or put the entire thing into PL/SQL, or decouple it and precalculate and store in a table which can then be used by your SQL. In general as a predominant pattern (at least historically), PL/SQL invokes SQL when needed, not so much the other way around.

Comment: If a row-producing (e.g. pipelined) function called in the FROM clause, there is more a legitimate case that could be made for doing heavy-lifting in the function. However in most cases you should be able to write a more complex SQL to do the work without needing to store transient data in PL/SQL. This is particularly true now that we have CTEs (common table expressions, or "WITH" clause) which provide a kind of GTT functionality that endures only for the SQL execution and can be used to break up a very complex SQL into discrete steps and reuse transient data within SQL without recomputing it.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks again, you're right, of course. Though CTE is quite limited in that its derived tables can be only be used in a few queries and not throughout the function domain. Also, I thought that logical blocks are better implemented as a unit, like in a function. But it is better to decouple problematic parts, as you say. How can I give you points, since you merely commented the question and not posted the comments as an answer?

Comment: I feel like this kind of "answer" merely points you in the right direction without being a complete answer to your question. A proper answer would require a large investment of time (time taken from my real job) to write up different architectural patterns and that's too large of a topic. Good luck!